# Find files changed in last 15 mins excluding some child directories and tar it up

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, find

I am trying to find files inside a parent directory which are modified in the last 15 mins. I want to exclude some child directories which I know does not change to speed up the process. and also feed the find result in a tar.gz.

the folder structure is

/upgrade/Rabc

/upgrade/Rdef   i.e (the name is preceeded by R)

I tried:
find /upgrade/ -mmin -15 -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cjf /storage/fileschanged.tar.gz

It takes a hell lot of time. The last one I tried had taken over 45 mins and was still running. The /upgrade/ folder is about 100 Gigs.
The reason for finding in 15 mins interval is because there is a cron job which alters the files every 15 mins.

Also I want to exclude the folders

/upgrade/Rabc/Weblogic

/upgrade/Rabc/ears

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use another pipe before the xargs?

```
find /upgrade/ -type f -mmin -15 -print0 | egrep -v "(Weblogic|ears)" | xargs -0 tar -cjf /storage/fileschanged.tar.gz
```

Comment: It gives me the error: 
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
However I see that the files are modified in the last 15 minutes.